# Number of discontinuous values

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

We have to find the number of values of $x$ at which the function $$ f(x) = \frac{2x^5-8x^2+11}{x^4+4x^3+8x^2+8x+4}$$ is discontinuous.

I thought that since both numerator and denominator are polynomials, and so are continuous, that the function would be continuous except when the denominator is zero.

But I am unable to find points where the denominator is zero.

Comment: Why would the function be a polynomial when the denominator isn't zero? Is it not a rational function then?

Comment: @MXYMXY funtion is not a polynomial , both numerator and denominator are polynomial.

Comment: That is what I am saying. I found your third line confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is never discontinuous because $x^4+4x^3+8x^2+8x+4\neq0$.

Comment: How can we say it is never zero

Comment: Because $x^4+4x^3+8x^2+8x+4=(x^2+2x+2)^2.$

That quadratic is clearly positive for all $x$.

Comment: Of course if we were to allow complex values for $x$, the denominator will have roots.  Such arguments $x$ are called *poles* in the theory of analytic functions.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, but complex roots are irrelevant to finding a function's discontinuities.

Answer (score 2):

Note $(x+1)^4=x^4+4x^3+6x^2+4x+1$.

Then, $$x^4+4x^3+8x^2+8x+4=(x+1)^4+2x^2+4x+3=(x+1)^4+2(x+1)^2+1$$

Thus we conclude that it is never discontinuous because  $$x^4+4x^3+8x^2+8x+4=(x^2+2x+2)^2>0$$